# C# Check if sections intersect

Tags: c#, function, directions

I have a list of N consecutive vertical and horizontal sections of fixed dimensions in a form of a succession of directions (right → ; left ←; down ↓; up ↑).
The program should return true if the sections intersect.
For example:
N = 6: { up, left, down, down, right, up} - return True.
I got the coordinates for every section, but I don't really know how to finish this.
Any ideeas?

```
static (int, int) GetCoordinates(string[] sectionDirection, int numberOfSections)
{
    (int X, int Y) pos = (0, 0);
    foreach (string move in sectionDirection)
    {
        switch (move)
        {
            case "left":
                pos = (0, 0);
                pos.X--;
                break;
            case "right":
                pos = (0, 0);
                pos.X++;
                break;
            case "down":
                pos = (0, 0);
                pos.Y--;
                break;
            case "up":
                pos = (0, 0);
                pos.Y++;
                break;
        }
    }

    return (pos.X, pos.Y);
}

static bool CheckSectionsIntersect(string[] sectionDirection, int numberOfSections)
{
    // I need help here.
}
```

Comment: Why are you resetting the `pos` to 0,0 for each move?  Just keep a `HashSet<(int, int)>` and check if the result of each move hits a position that you've already been to.  Unless by intersection you actually mean loop in which case you just need to check that the final position is 0,0.

Comment: Sounds like a cool beginner coding interview question.  I like it.  Start by explaining the algorithm in _words_, then graduate to _pseudo-code_, then we'll tackle the actual C# code.  But we need to know your approach.  How would you solve the problem if you had to do it manually?

Comment: Also you don't need `numberOfSections` assuming you want to use all the moves in the array.

Comment: Please clarify whether by _intersect_ you mean 1) to visit any set of coordinates more than once, or 2) to conclude at (0,0).  (or something else).

Comment: @Wyck The term interseciton made me think they want to detect if the path crosses itself which is why I mention the use of a HasSet.  But like I said if they are actually checking for a closed loop they don't need that.

Comment: For sure don't reset the position to the origin at each case.

Comment: @Wyck I mean if the path crosses itself.

Comment: @juharr I am not allowed to use HashSet<(int, int)>, List, Dictionary.
I am a begginer that is following a course and I haven't reach that point yet.

Comment: @Skike Can you use an array?  If so just save the positions into an array and then search to see if any position is repeated.  Not as efficient as a HashSet but it should work.

Comment: @juharr I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Create an array `var positions = new (int, int)[sectionDirection.Length];` and just add the positions as you calculate them (remove the the `pos = (0, 0)` bit in each case).   Then do a search on the array to see if any position occurs more than once.

Comment: @juhaar Can you help me with a piece of program because I don't understand where to put this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest code change I can think of would be to use something that will remember all the visited locations and can tell you whether or not you have visited a location before.  Such an object needs a way to *add* a location to its memory, and needs a way to *test* to see if a location is remembered.

Believe it or not, you can just use `string` to do this.  Because a tuple will convert to a string as `(0, 0)` with parentheses and commas delimiting the fields, it's fine to just concatenate them all into a string and then use `string.Contains` to see if a location exists.  (This is kind of silly, and I'd prefer a HashSet instead of a string for efficiency, but you said in your comment you cannot.)

It will build up a string that looks like:
`(0, 0)(0, 1)(-1, 1)(-1, 0)`...

To remember a location, append it to the end of the string with the `+=` operator.  When you do `memory += pos` then `pos` will automatically get converted to a string using `ToString()`.

To check if a location exists, use `memory.Contains(pos.ToString())`.  In this case you have to explicitly convert the tuple to a string with `.ToString()` to pass it as an argument to `.Contains`.

```
private static bool CheckForIntersections(string[] sectionDirection)
{
    string memory = "";
    (int X, int Y) pos = (0, 0);
    memory += pos;
    foreach (string move in sectionDirection)
    {
        switch (move)
        {
            case "left":
                pos.X--;
                break;
            case "right":
                pos.X++;
                break;
            case "down":
                pos.Y--;
                break;
            case "up":
                pos.Y++;
                break;
        }
        if (memory.Contains(pos.ToString())) return true; // It was revisited
        memory += pos;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but there is one more problem  to this, the program works well if the sections intersect in a point, I've adapted it for when the sections intersect in a line, but it doesn't work when they don't intersect. For example: 4, down, left, up left(0, -1) (-1, 0) (0, 1) (-1, 0) the program must return false.

Comment: Sorry.  I pasted a version where I hadn't removed the `pos = (0, 0)`'s yet.  I shall update.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in one line essentially.

```
public static (int x, int y)[] GetCoordinates(Directions directions)
{
   // accumulate a list with coordinates here
}

public static bool Intersect(params Direction[] directions)
{
    var coord = GetCoordinates(directions);
    return coord.Distinct().Count() < coord.Count();
}
```

Check if any of the coordinates are duplicates by seeing if the set of distinct values has less elements that the full set of coordinates.

PS. I prefer to use `enum` for things with finite values like directions

```
public enum Direction
{
    None,
    Left,
    Right,
    Up,
    Down,
}
```

Comment: Their `GetCoordinates` returns a single `(int, int)` so this isn't going to work.

Comment: @juharr - I omitted the signature of `GetCoordinates()` by mistake. See update now.

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine yourself being on an infinitely large chess board and somebody tells you to put a step in any direction he tells you. The only way to know if you have already crossed a point is by putting some stuff on every point you have passed and in case you get the command to go to such a point, you shout "Intersect!" :-)

If it's just about getting back to your starting point, you just count the amount of commands you've received: if the number of "up"s equals the number of "down"s and the number of "left"s equals the number of "right"s, you know that you have reached your starting point.
If you are not allowed to keep four counters, you can do it with two variables, "hor" (for horizontal) and "ver" (for vertical):

```
up means ver++
down means ver--
left means hor--
right means hor++
```

If, at the end, both "hor" and "ver" are back to zero, you have reached again your starting point.

Have fun :-)